Please what can I do when looker studio linked to ODK central brings up this response?
Error response: Debug
ODK Central by UW Impact++
SyntaxError: Unterminated string in JSON at position 52428057 (line 1 column 52428058)
getData:1358
I linked the looker studio to my ODK central using the designated URL connector link. While this worked for over 2 weeks, visualizing the data directly from the ODK, it stopped recently.
